# Performing query that doesn't return desire result with like operator

Tags: database

Whenever i am trying to do query with this i am getting words which length is 15 .

```
select * from 'Table_A' where LENGTH('value') = 5 and value LIKE 'A%S';
```

Answer (score 3):

`LENGTH('value')` is always 5. Thus it returns only values that match `LIKE 'A%S'`

Fix it with:

```
SELECT * FROM Table_A where LENGTH(value) = 5 and value LIKE 'A%S';
```

Comment: here my field name is 'value'

Comment: is there anything wrong ,because now i am getting only the data which length is 15 .

Comment: The field name is not `'value'`, it is `value`, or `\`value\`` (the quotes define a static string, the backticks would reference the field, though you don't need them here)

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from 'Table_A' where LENGTH(value) = 5 and value LIKE 'A%S';
```

You were checking the length of the literal string 'value', which is always 5. Remove the quotes so you check the length of the data in the column.